# Como descompactar um string compactada no padrão GZIP em PHP?

Tags: php, gzip

Preciso **descompactar uma string** **compactada no padrão GZIP** em PHP. O tipo do campo é base64Binary.

Já tentei:
`gzinflate($string);
gzdecode($string);
gzuncompress($string);`

Porém só tive **retorno de "data error"** na utilização das três funções.
Como eu poderia solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o campo é `base64Binary` (provavelmente um webservice, SOAP talvez) então tem que usar [**`base64_decode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) e depois [**`gzdecode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php), algo como:

```
$string = base64_decode($string);
$string = gzdecode($string);

var_dump($string); //Para testar o resultado
```